# Should I create a static Vertx instance for an object in a Vertx application?

Tags: vert.x

I'm using vertx in my project nad I guess that I had a terrible idea when I create a Java class like this

```
public class MyClass {

   static Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

   public void run() {
       vertx.getOrCreateContext().runOnContext(event -> {
           // run something
       });
   }
}
```

Everything I run in this run() function will be run asynchronous but I'm not sure that it's recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have a vert.x application, you can get the Vertx object in a class by extending the `AbstractVerticle` and getting the vert.x object from it using the `getVertx()` method.

Also, `Vertx.vertx()` always creates a new instance. It's better to use something like `Vertx.currentContext().getOwner()`

Remember that static objects are created before non-static objects and non-static methods being run. This means that if there are some configs/checks that needs to be done at bootstrap (for example metrics), they could be missed, unless maybe also done in a static context.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice against doing this. The reason is, that it would heaviliy reduce your ability to write tests for all the classes that rely on that static Vertx instance.

Use dependency injection instead (or use Verticles as described in the other answer).

Comment: yeah you're right, I'm finding way to run my code asynchronously by using vertx instance in AbstracrVerticle but it does not work as my expectation. Can you give me a document about dependency injection in vertx.

Comment: I would suggest to use Google Guice :)